# Should I be liable for the cost of replacing calliper's when the garage couldn't find the issue on multiple occasions?

Tags: brakes, caliper, mechanics-trade

Our family car had the brake pads and discs replaced in December, about a month later they started to make a strange sound when you pressed the brake pedal - not every time, sometimes much more than others sometimes not at all for entire journeys. It sounds like a windscreen wiper dragging down a dry windscreen. We took the car into the garage 3 times, each time they said they couldn't hear it and couldn't find anything wrong with the brakes, suggested it was road debris or possible a tiny bit of rust that will wear away after a while.

Finally we recorded the noise and took it into them, the regional manager said he knew exactly what it was, the brake was at a slight angle meaning the edge would rub on the brake before settling. They are going to take the brake apart clean it down and set everything straight. They then said the caliper will need changing but will be relatively cheap (£290).

My question (eventually) has this not been caused due to their original install/changing brake pads and not being diagnosed sooner? are they liable for the new caliper?